# Custom frame for QLineEdit

Tags: qt

(Working with Qt 4.8.4)

I'd like to create a custom frame for QLineEdit. One that has been created in photoshop and I have it in three images (as it needs to stretch in width):

[image]

1. left side image
2. center streetchable image
3. right side image

I'd like to find a way to replace the look of the QTLineEdit to this, while still retaining the edit visuals look/feel inside of it. It's just the frame I'm looking t replace.

How do I go about it? If I override paintEvent nothing is visible, not even what I type, not even the blinking cursor.

Comment: Did you have a look at Qt Style sheets already? Seems like you could do it with that (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlineedit / http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model / http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html#border-image-prop)

Comment: I will give border-image a try. thanks. if this works- I'll ask you to  mention in in an answer so that I can credit you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I think I nailed it:

I am setting the following stylesheet for my QLineEdit objects:

```
this->ui->myLineEdit->setStyleSheet("border-image: url(input_bg.png) 5 5 5 5 stretch stretch;border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;");
```

I am using "5" because in the image I used, a 5x5 cut of each corner encapsulates the area that doesn't stretch gracefully due to gradients within.

this makes sure that the border will work nicely when the edit control is of variable sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- create your own class `CustomLineEdit` inherited from `QLineEdit`,
- load/free your pictures in constructor/destructor of `CustomLineEdit`,
- reimplement `paintEvent()` in `CustomLineEdit` yourself,
- in `paintEvent()` place all pictures as you need.

Comment: yes, but i need the standard paint behavior applied (minus the frame). That is not easy to achieve, partially copying stuff off of QLineEdit is a bit tricky with all that crazy d-pointer Q_D implementations.